# jQuery DataTables adding hyperlink with row.add() method

Tags: datatables

I am dynamically adding new rows to jQuery data table using `row.add()` method. I am using angular js to get data from api and adding them to the table as new rows. below is my table rows structure.

```
<tr ng-repeat="datum in userData">
                <td>{{datum.no}}</td>
                <td><a href="/Public/User/{{datum.subId}}">{{datum.fullName}}</a></td>
                <td>{{datum.productsIntoAccount}}</td>
                <td>{{datum.state}}</td>
                <td>{{datum.country}}</td>
</tr>
```

The code responsible for adding rows dynamically is given below.

```
datatable = $("#data-table").DataTable({
                        "responsive": true,
                        "paging": false

});
var data = response.data;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    datatable.row.add([
                        data[i].no,
                        data[i].fullName,
                        data[i].productsIntoAccount,
                        data[i].state,
                        data[i].country,
                        data[i].subId
                    ]).draw(false);
}
```

As you can see in table row structure, `fullName` is a hyperlink which takes `subId` from api data to add it in href. My question is that how do I add hyperlink using `row.add()` method in table data?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Based on suggestion given in comment section I have simplified the answer.

```
var data = response.data;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    datatable.row.add([
                        data[i].no,
                        '<a href="/Public/User/' + data[i].subId + '">' + data[i].fullName + '</a>',
                        data[i].productsIntoAccount,
                        data[i].state,
                        data[i].country
                    ]).draw(false);
                }
```

Comment: That's not correct way to do it. You can either use string with HTML in `row.add()` or use `columns.render` option to produce content for the cell based on row data.

Comment: String with html seems easy to implement. I will implement it then i will update the answer.

Comment: With string you would need to be careful escaping HTML special characters such as `<` or `>` in `fullName` and `subId`.